# WGCNA Analysis - Dendrogram with phenotype and gene expression data

Tags: r, dendrogram

In WGCNA, I need to plot the sample dendrogram with the phenotype colors in the gene expression data to examine outliers.

I have the following code:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1), cex = 0.6, mar = c(0,4,2,0))
plotDendroAndColors(sampleTree2, phenoColors,groupLabels = colnames(pDat.sub),main = "Sample dendrogram and trait heatmap")
```

I am getting an error:

> Error in plotOrderedColors(dendro$order, colors = colors, rowLabels =
>   rowLabels,  :    ERROR: length of colors vector not compatible with
>   number of objects in 'order'.

Can someone help me out?

I don't know what's the possible reason for this error.

Comment: You should take a look at the dendextend R package. https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/31/22/3718/240978/dendextend-an-R-package-for-visualizing-adjusting

Comment: Specifically at color_branches
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/Quick_Introduction.html